# Is there a way to make suggested action a numbered list on Botframework v4?

Tags: c#, botframework

I have this suggested action that displays button. Is there a way to make it like a numbered list? And then the user will just need to type in the number?

```cs
return await stepContext.PromptAsync(TextPromptId, new PromptOptions
{
    Prompt = new Activity
    {
        Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
        Text = $"Choose a question or type your own question.",
        SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
        {                             
            Actions = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction() { Title = "This is Sample Question 1", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "This is Sample Question 1" },
                new CardAction() { Title = "This is Sample Question 2", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "This is Sample Question 2" },
                new CardAction() { Title = "This is Sample Question 3", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "This is Sample Question 3" },
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Could you not just send the person the numbered list through the normal reply mechanism rather than using the approach you've taken?

Comment: @user10860402 Marking the solution as accepted serves the greater Stack Overflow community and anyone with a similar question. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a Choice Prompt and setting the `ListStyle` in `promptOptions` to `ListStyle.List`.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Code Snippet - C# SDK v4.5.0**

```cs
private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> TransportStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // WaterfallStep always finishes with the end of the Waterfall or with another dialog; here it is a Prompt Dialog.
    // Running a prompt here means the next WaterfallStep will be run when the users response is received.
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt),
        new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter your mode of transport."),
            Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(new List<string> { "Car", "Bus", "Bicycle" }),
            Style = ListStyle.List
        }, cancellationToken);
}
```

Hope this helps!