# Apply list style for botframework v4 choice prompt: NodeJS

Tags: node.js, botframework

Hi I'm trying to add a list style in the choices of botbuilder-dialog; Botframework v4, NodeJS.

I'm trying to implement it using the code below, but its seems that the list style does not take any effect in the choices. It should prompt a numbered list but it prompts a button like list.

```
const{ChoicePrompt, ListStyle} = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
const CHOICE_PROMPT = 'CHOICE_PROMPT';

//Set up ChoicePrompt
var cp = new ChoicePrompt(CHOICE_PROMPT);
cp.Style = ListStyle.list;
this.addDialog(cp);

this.choicesX = ['Pick1', 'Pick2', 'Pick3'];


//function
async test(stepContext){
    return await stepContext.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, {
        prompt: 'Select item:',
        choices: this.choicesX
    });
}
```

What is the correct way to add a list style in the choices of choice prompt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make suggested action a numbered list on Botframework v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672001/is-there-a-way-to-make-suggested-action-a-numbered-list-on-botframework-v4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a duplicate of this StackOverflow question; however, the answer is in C#. This is how you would set the style prompt option in the Node SDK.

**Node SDK v4.5**

```
const { ListStyle, ... } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');

async transportStep(step) {
    // WaterfallStep always finishes with the end of the Waterfall or with another dialog; here it is a Prompt Dialog.
    // Running a prompt here means the next WaterfallStep will be run when the users response is received.
    return await step.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, {
        prompt: 'Please enter your mode of transport.',
        choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices(['Car', 'Bus', 'Bicycle']),
        style: ListStyle.list
    });
}
```

The list style options are `none`, `auto`, `inline`, `list`, `suggestedAction`, and `heroCard`.

Hope this helps!