# How to prevent Suggested Actions from being converted to text?

Tags: node.js, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am building a chatbot with Microsoft Botframework V4 using Node js.
When I send a SuggestedActions to the user with short text it works perfectly as shown in this image [Suggested Action Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9o0a.jpg). However, when the text of the buttons exceeds appx 20 characters they get converted to an ordered list with text.[Buttons converted to text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXhTi.jpg)
Is there a way to force the bot to send Buttons even if the text is long?

```js
// this works perfectly
let buttons = ["Red", "Blue", "Yello"];
return await step.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, "Please Choose One", buttons);


// this does not work as expected, the buttons are converted to text and are //shown in a list

let buttons = ["I like Red and Blue",
    "I do not like any colo ",
    "Please stop   asking questions"
];
return await step.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, "Please Choose One", buttons);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This worked

```
 let buttons = ["I like Red and Blue",
        "I do not like any colo ",
        "Please stop   asking questions"
    ];

let suggestedActions = MessageFactory.suggestedActions([buttons], 'Please choose one')

return await step.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, suggestedActions);
```

Found the best answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57064662/10531724